# Relación con pivote en laravel error en columna desconocida

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy trantando de unir 2 tablas, con relacion muchos a muchos, pero me aparece un error con inner join donde al parecer hay un id faltante, pero como puedo pasar ese id?

Events to UserEvents

Error sql al hacer get en la ultima parte al parecer no recibe un **id**:

```
 Unknown column 'event_school_user.' in 'on clause' 
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `event_schools` inner join `event_school_user` on `event_schools`.`id` = `event_school_user`.``
```

*Model User:*

```
public function event_schools() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EventSchool::class)->using(EventSchoolUser::class);
    }
```

*EventSchool: acá creo puede ser el error*

```
class EventSchool extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'event_schools';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $fillable = ['event_school_id','user_id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function event_schools() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EventSchool::class);
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

*EventSchoolUser:*

```
class EventSchoolUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'event_school_user';
    
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de las relaciones de mi tabla, estan de igual forma, solo cambian los nombres de las tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ahora lo que trato es hacer un Select * from eventos a la tabla de eventos(EventSchool): algo así

```
$events = $user->event_schools()->paginate(12);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien es cierto que Laravel permite el trabajo de un modelo [*para la tabla intermedia*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), lo anterior no me parece necesario y si lo reformulamos creería que consigues el resultado esperado de una manera simple.

1. Entonces basado en lo anterior yo eliminaría el modelo `EventSchool`
2. Luego entonces solo deberían quedar 2 modelos (**me vpy a basar en el ejemplo que provees**):

   - Usuario
   - Evento
3. En cada uno de los modelos deberías declarar la relación que los vincula con la tabla intermedia:

   - Modelo `Usuario`

     ```
     public function eventos()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Evento::class, 'eventos_user', 'iduser', 'idevents');
     }
     ```
   - Modelo `Evento`

     ```
     public function usuarios()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Usuario::class, 'eventos_user', 'idvents', 'iduser');
     }
     ```
4. Luego de lo anterior si buscas obtener todos los eventos de un usuario, puedes escribir la consulta de esta forma:

   ```
   $usuarioId = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

   $usuarioId->eventos()->paginate(12);
   ```

Comentario final:

- Sugiero leas a detalle [la doc. relacionada](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) para comprender a mayor detalle el uso de los argumentos 2 al 4 en cada una de las relaciones.

Comment: Funciono, tal cual